# Is there a monotonic function discontinuous over some dense set?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Can we construct a monotonic function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that there is a dense set in some interval $(a,b)$ for which $f$ is discontinuous at all points in the dense set?  What about a strictly monotonic function?

My intuition tells me that such a function is impossible.

Here is a rough sketch of an attempt at proving that such a function does not exist: we could suppose a function satisfies these conditions.  Take an $\epsilon > 0$ and two points $x,y$ in this dense set such that $x<y$.  Then, $f(x)<f(y)$ because if they are equal, then the function is constant at all points in between, and there is another element of $X$ between $x$ and $y$, which would be a contradiction.  Take $f(y)-f(x)$.  By the Archimedean property of the reals, $f(y)-f(x)<n\epsilon$ for some $n$.

However, after this point, I am stuck.  Could we somehow partition $(x,y)$ into $n$ subintervals and conclude that there must be some point on the dense set that is continuous?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Such a function is possible.

Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers, and define

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\sum_{q_n\le x}\frac1{2^n}\;.\tag{1}$$

The series $\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{2^n}$ is absolutely convergent, so $(1)$ makes sense. If $x<y$, there is some rational $q_n\in(x,y)$, and clearly $f(y)\ge f(x)+\frac1{2^n}$, so $f$ is monotone increasing. However, $f$ is discontinuous at every rational:

$$\lim_{x\to {q_n}^-}f(x)=\sum_{q_k<q_n}\frac1{2^k}<\sum_{q_k\le q_n}\frac1{2^k}=f(q_n)\;.$$

Thus, $f$ is discontinuous on a set that is dense in $\Bbb R$ (and in every open interval of $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Seriously? I was just typing that...

Comment: @Asaf: It’s a pretty standard example, I think.

Comment: True.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: It seems that this assumes that there is an enumeration of the rational numbers that preserves ordering on the reals, unless I'm reading it wrong.  That is $q_n>q_m$ iff $n>m$.  Is there such an enumeration?

Comment: @AndrewSalmon: Of course there is not. It also does not assume that.

Comment: @Andrew: It does not, which is a good thing, since there clearly is no such enumeration.

Comment: Oh...ok. So you're just rearranging an absolutely convergent series.  +1

Comment: So is having a monotonic function discontinuous over $X$ a necessary *and* sufficient condition for $X$ being an at most countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$?  There are no uncountable sets for which monotonic functions can be discontinuous over, right?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, and yes. You can use the same trick to build a function that’s discontinuous at each point of any countably infinite $X\subseteq\Bbb R$, and of course building a function with a specified finite set of discontinuities is no problem at all. And a monotone function can have at most countably many points of discontinuity.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon A good thing to google is Froda's theorem.

Comment: Also of possible interest are the references and comments for Theorem 1 and Theorem 1' in my sci.math post [References for Continuity Sets](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5447961).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you mentioned in one of comments: "You can use the same trick to build a function that’s discontinuous at each point of any countably infinite X⊆R."    Can we build a function defined on E⊆R that is discontinuous only at countable infinite subset C⊆E

Comment: @Sushil: Yes; just replace the rationals by a countable dense subset of $E$. Note, though, that any isolated point of $E$ will be a point of continuity of any function defined on $E$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott that exactly I was trying and asked a question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037457/countable-subset-and-monotonic-function  as mentioned in my question if E=[0,1] and C is set of rational points in [0,1] then above function doesn't help at 0

Comment: @Sushil: Change the definition very slightly by setting $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ya this is okay in case of [0,1] but what if E is general set. what example we can give?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott could you explain why $f(x) \geq f(y)+\dfrac{1}{2^n}$?
I was thinking that  for $x,y$ for $y<x$ $f(y)\geq f(x)$

Comment: @AsafKaragila You mentioned that this is a fairly standard example so I ask, does this find application someplace else? (I know that is not necessarily the case, but I was curious).

Answer (score 6):

For those interested, here is a slightly more rigorous proof that the construction exists using measure theory.

We will define a function $H$ which is continuous from the left at ever $x \in [0,1]$ but is only continuous from the right at the irrationals. To build such a function we need the folliowing scaffolding.

First let $\psi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ be a bijection enumerating the rationals in the interval $[0,1]$. Then define $B(x) = \{n : \psi(n)< x\}$ or equivalently $B(x) = \psi^{-1}([0,x))$. Finally let $\mu: P(\mathbb{N}) \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the counting measure. We additionally define a measure $\nu: P(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\nu(A) = \int_A 2^{-n} d \mu(n).$$
The measure $\nu$ has the additional property that $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\nu(\mathbb{N}) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 2^{-n} \mu({n}) = 1 < \infty.$

We claim that the function $H(x) = \nu(B(x))$ has the properties of $f$ in the statement of the problem. We will first show that for
every $x \in [0,1]$ the function $H(x)$ is left continuous. Take a sequence of $x_k \to x$ from the left, we can then rearrange the sequence to be strict monotonic. It follows that if $k > m$ then $$B(x_m) = \{n: \psi(n) < x_m < x_k < x\} \subset \{n: \psi(n) < x_k < x\} = B(x_k).$$ By the 
finiteness of $\nu$ we have that by upward measure continuity
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} H(x_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \nu(B(x_k)) = \nu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B(x_k) \right) = \nu(\left \{n: \psi(n) < x\}\right ) = H(x).$$
Note that if $ n \in \bigcup B(x_k)$  there is an $K$ so that $\psi(n) < x_k < x $ so any $n$ with $\psi(n) < x$ is in $\bigcup B(x_k).$

Next we claim that $H$ is only right continuous only when $x$ is irrational. Take a sequence of $x_k \to x$ from the right and rearrange the sequence to be  strict montonic. It follows that if $k > m$ then $$B(x_m) = \{n: \psi(n) < x_m\} \supset \{n: \psi(n) < x_k < x_m\} = B(x_k).$$ By finiteness of $\nu$ and downard measure continuity
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} H(x_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \nu(B(x_k)) = \nu\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty B(x_k) \right) = \nu(\left \{n: \psi(n) < x_k\ \forall k\}\right ).$$

If $x$ is irrational then $m \in \{n: \psi(n) < x_k\ \forall k\}$ implies that $\psi(m) < x$ and if $\psi(m) < x$ then $\psi(m) < x_k$ for all $k$ so $\{n: \psi(n) < x_k\ \forall k\} = B(x)$ and $H(x_k) \to H(x)$ from the right. If $x$ is rational then $x= \psi(q)$ for some
$q \in \mathbb{N}.$ Thus $x < x_k \forall k$ implies that $\{n: \psi(n) < x_k\ \forall k\} = B(x) + \{q\} = D$. It follows that $\nu(D) = \nu(B(x)) + 2^{-q} > H(x)$. So $H(x_k) \to H(x) + 2^{-q} \neq H(x)$ from the right, and so $H$ is not right continuous at the rationals.

We have thus shown that for any $x \in [0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, any sequence $x_k \to x$ has the property $\lim H(x_k) = x$ from the left and the right, and if $x \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ then if $x_k \to x$, $\lim H(x_k)$ does not exist. Therefore $H$ is continuous at every irrational and discontinuous at every rational.

You can then repeat this construction along the whole real line by adding the nearest integer each time.