# Monotonic function non-continuous in each rational

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity

How can I prove that exists a monotonic non-decreasing function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that isn't continuous in every rational of its domain?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172753/is-there-a-monotonic-function-discontinuous-over-some-dense-set